# Local linear regression: number of grid points?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, local-statistics

Local linear regression is a popular tool. How can one choose the number of grid points for which to estimate the unknown function on?

Comment: One rule of thumb: use enough points that it looks like a smooth curve when you plot it.